# Why does Java length function ignore \?

Tags: java

How does string.length work in Java?

I have the following string as:
`String str = "Hello\tWorld!";`

Executing the .length() function, I would expect an output of 13 or 11, however .length() ignores the \ and returns 12. Why does .length() return 12? It's ignoring the \, but why isn't it also ignoring the following 't'?

Comment: ``\`` is an escape character, it adds special meaning to the next character, in this case, it represents a tab character

Comment: Look into String literals. @MadProgrammer use double `\``.

Comment: @Pshemo Hehehe, took me long enough to get it to display :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Java literal string, the `\t` represents *one* character, a tab character. This conversion is done by the compiler when it reads your source code. At runtime, the `.length()` method does not even see the `\` at all (since it's not there).